# Divergence of the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n!)^n}{n^{4n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

After applying the root test to this series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n!^n}{n^{4n}},$$ I get $$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{n!}{n^4}.$$ How would I complete this problem to show whether or not it is convergent?

Comment: Your limit is $\infty$ which implies the series diverges.

Comment: Hint: for $n \ge 3$, we have $n! \ge n(n-1)(n-2)$ by ignoring all the terms after $n-2$.  What does this mean for $\lim_{n\to\infty} n!/n^2$?  How could you modify this to understand $\lim_{n\to\infty} n!/n^4$?

Answer (score 1):

So far so good.  Now let's show

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{n^4}=\infty$$

Using Erick Wong's hint, notice that for $n\ge 5$ we have $n!\ge n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)$.  It follows that:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{n^4}\ge\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)}{n^4}=\infty$$

The above limit is infinite because the numerator is a fifth degree polynomial, and the denominator is a fourth degree polynomial.  By the comparison theorem, we're done.